# Form custom with method GET remove form_build_id and op from GET variables

Tags: 8, forms

If I create a custom form with get method:

```
$form['#method'] = 'get';
```

When I click the submit button, many variables are populated with GET
Can I remove them cleanly according to the drupal logic?

Answer (score 4):

You need to alter the form after it has been built, for example

```
$build = [];
$build['filter'] = $this->formBuilder->getForm(LibrarySearch::class);
$build['filter']['form_id']['#access'] = FALSE;
$build['filter']['form_build_id']['#access'] = FALSE;
$build['filter']['form_token']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

Once the form has been turned into a render array, you can set the access to `FALSE` for those items. This is also documented in the core Search module.

Answer (score 1):

For me, unsetting inside form_alter didn't work. I had to do it in a different way.

Add this inside form_alter hook.

```
  $form['#after_build'][] = 'function_name';
```

Later add a separate function and unset inside that.

```
function function_name($form){

  // Unset variables to cleanup the url after submission
    unset($form['form_token']);
    unset($form['form_build_id']);
    unset($form['form_id']);
    return $form;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem.

Implement a hook form alter in your corresponding module in the

`[name_of_your_module].module` file, just add

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 * Need to don't see the parameters 'form_build_id' and 'form_id' in the url.
 */
function hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  unset($form['form_build_id'], $form['form_id']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Needs to alter the form to unset  **form_id** and **form_build_id**. In bellow code **formid** is the id of the form where you want to remove **form_id** and **form_build_id**.

function mymodule_form_formid_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

unset($form['form_build_id'], $form['form_id']);

}